# html-webpack-plugin is not inserting options.title

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to dynamically inject title to html via webpack and html-webpack-plugin. I am using handlebar templating engine. But I have failed to inject `title`. here is what my webpack config looks like -

```
/*
|----------------------------------------------
| setting up webpack build process for app
| @author: jahid haque 
| @copyright: mysite, 2019
|----------------------------------------------
*/

const SriPlugin = require('webpack-subresource-integrity');
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const Path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

const Optim = {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
        minSize: 0,
        cacheGroups: {
            vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name(module) {
                    const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
                    return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

const Module = {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            exclude: /node_module/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.handlebars$/,
            exclude: /node_module/,
            use: {
                loader: 'handlebars-loader',
            },
        },
    ],
};


module.exports = [

    {
        entry: {
            home: Path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/home/home.controller.jsx'),
        },
        output: {
            path: Path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
            filename: Path.join('./js/[name].[contenthash].js'),
            publicPath: '',
            crossOriginLoading: 'anonymous',
        },
        optimization: Optim,

        module: Module,

        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: true,
                hash: true,
                title: 'home page. know how we work',
                template: './src/index.handlebars',
                filename: Path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.html'),
            }),
            new Webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
            new SriPlugin({
                hashFuncNames: ['sha512', 'sha384'],
                enabled: true,
            }),
            new Webpack.NamedChunksPlugin(),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin({
                cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['./public/js/'],
            }),
            new WebpackMd5Hash(),
        ],

    },       

    {
        entry: {
            style: Path.resolve(__dirname, './src/scss/app.scss'),
        },
        output: {
            path: Path.resolve(__dirname, './public/css/'),
        },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: 'styles.css',
            }),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.s?css$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader',
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    },
];
```

and my htmlWebpack plugin settings are -

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   inject: true,
   hash: true,
   title: 'welcome to home page',
   template: './src/index.handlebars',
   filename: 'index.html',
 }),
```

In my `index.handlebars` file I am applying this -

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Test site | <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        {{>partials/head}}
    </head>

    <body class="d-flex flex-column h-100 pt-60">

        {{>partials/nav}}

        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <main role = 'main' class="flex-shrink-0 min-height-750">
            <div id="welcomeHome"></div>    
        </main>  

        {{>partials/footer}}

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "chefcooks",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://hidhaque@bitbucket.org/hidhaque/chefcooks.git"
  },
  "author": "jahid haque",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/hidhaque/chefcooks#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "handlebars": "^4.1.1",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "platform": "^1.3.5",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.6",
    "webpack-subresource-integrity": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

But the output for title in my `index.html` remains -

```
<title>Test title | <%- HtmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

here is the `.babelrc` -

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", 
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "transform-async-to-generator",
        [
            "transform-class-properties", 
            { "spec": true }, 
        ]
    ]
}
```

Could use some help here. I am new to this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce the issue but I couldn't, insted I made this example and everything is working fine:
**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const WebpackHTMLPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.handlebars/,
                use: 'handlebars-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackHTMLPlugin({
            inject: true,
            hash: true,
            title: 'My custom title!',
            template: './template.hbs'
        })
    ]
}
```

**Handlebars template:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title }}</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Just in case I'll show you my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-hbs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.config"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Looking at your code I'm wondering that you're using React, maybe, could you try this code and discuss the ouputs? Hope this answer throw some lights on your issue. Cheers, sigfried.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to resolve the issue, you can see the simple change I've made to `index.handlebars`. Apparently as pointed out in [html-webpack-plugin documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md#3-setting-a-loader-using-the-moduleloaders-syntax) when you use a different loader it will disable the `ejs fallback loader`, I'm assuming that beacause of this the `<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options %></title>` is not working in your case that's why I've changed the template to use `Handlebars strings interpolation`. I'm still thinking this is weird and maybe I'm missing something else but in any case, this is working right now. Always glad to help, cheers sigfried.

Comment: **sigfried** hey mate, I have edited my question and added full `webpack.config.js`, `package.json`, `index.handlebars`. I don't see much difference with your code mate. Can you please have a look? cheers.

Comment: sure, no problem

Comment: @jahid did you try removing `Test site | ` from  `<title>Test site | <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>`? For some reasons I don't quite understand that gave me some troubles. Everything else seems correct, can I see yout `.babelrc` too? Cheers

Comment: hey mate, thanks for the reply. I tried removing `Test site` from the title. didn't help. adding `babelrc` to my question. cheers.

Comment: @jahid Mate, again I've tried to reproduce the bug now configuring a simple React app like you're doing in the example and still works correctly :(. I'll take one last shot for now, check your `head` partial, that's the only thing I'm missing on my example and maybe that partial is overwriting the title in some magical way, for now, no more ideas. Cheers, sigfried.

Comment: **sigfried** apologies mate for delay response. I was very busy all day. In my `head.handlebars` I have nothing but some scripts tag and css. I have removed all partials from `index.handlebars` yet still in my `index.html` I have `<title><%=htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title%></title>`. Its driving me crazy now. I really don't know what to do here. Do you mind If I give you my code on codepen or somewhere like this? Cheers mate.

Comment: Sure @jahid that's perfect, sorry for the delay too.

Comment: hey mate, here is link for the repo `https://github.com/jahidhaque/handlebars-bug`. thanks a lot mate. cheers.

Comment: @jahid checkout the answer, I've updated the code and added some explanation of why I think it was wrong. Cheers

Comment: **sigfried** hey mate, it solved the issue. I can't thank you enough mate. I have looked everywhere but missed this. learnt something new today from you mate. Good you know you a little. Take care. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191879/discussion-between-sigfried-and-jahid).